# Use dynamic id to change background with hover on menu (DAWN THEME)

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, logical-operators

At the moment I have created an editable section from the customizer, where you can add the desktop and mobile images, and the menu. Now, the question is how to link these background images with each of the "Details-id" and that it changes when the user passes the mouse over it. I'm using nav-component, so I would like to just add modifications to global.js using code from dawn theme.

Here is the preview of this theme in development:
https://f0jfypzl040i0kcv-53196980409.shopifypreview.com

Could someone guide me? Thanks in advance!

---

this is what im using at the moment, where i have to add that new html code?

```js
<script>

    //megamenu hover
    let items = document.querySelector(".aside__nav").querySelectorAll("details");
    items.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
            item.setAttribute("open", true);
            item.querySelector("ul").addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
                item.removeAttribute("open");
            });
            item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
                item.removeAttribute("open");
            });
        });
    });

    //megamenu image show on hover
    var $activeElement = $(".megamenu-text");
    $(".custom-mega-img").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".megamenu-img").addClass( "active" );
    }, function(){
        $(".megamenu-img").removeClass( "active" );
    });

</script>
```

```css
nav.aside__nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    max-width: max-content;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.aside__triggers {
    list-style: none;
}

li.aside__trigger-container {
    padding: .5rem 0;
}

li.aside__link-container {
    list-style: none;
}

ul.aside__links {
    padding: 0;
}

.aside__trigger {
    font-size: calc(var(--font-heading-scale) * 1.3rem);
    background-color: transparent;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: currentColor;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}

summary.aside__sub-trigger {
    font-size: calc(var(--font-heading-scale) * 1.3rem);
}


ul.aside__sub-links {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 2.5rem;
}

a.aside__sub-link,
a.aside__link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: currentColor;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}

details-disclosure>details {
    position: inherit;
}

.list-menu--disclosure {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    width: 90% !important;
    min-width: 90% !important;
    z-index: 2 !important;
    height: 30vh;
}

span.megamenu-img {
    text-align: center;
    width: 65%;
}

.desktop-feature-img {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

span.megamenu-text {
    width: 35%;
}

span.megamenu-img.active .desktop-feature-img {
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
}

.list-menu__item--active .desktop-feature-img {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="landing__backgrounds">  
    {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
        <div class="landing__background" data-id="{{ block.id }}">
            <div class="background-box landing__background-image">
                {% if block.settings.image != blank and block.settings.image_2 != blank %}
                    <div class="banner__media{% if block.settings.image == blank and block.settings.image_2 == blank %} placeholder{% endif %}">
                        <img 
                            class="hidden-mobile"
                            srcset="{%- if block.settings.image.width >= 375 -%}{{ block.settings.image | image_url: width: 375 }} 375w,{%- endif -%}
                                {%- if block.settings.image.width >= 550 -%}{{ block.settings.image | image_url: width: 550 }} 550w,{%- endif -%}
                                {%- if block.settings.image.width >= 750 -%}{{ block.settings.image | image_url: width: 750 }} 750w,{%- endif -%}
                                {%- if block.settings.image.width >= 1100 -%}{{ block.settings.image | image_url: width: 1100 }} 1100w,{%- endif -%}
                                {%- if block.settings.image.width >= 1500 -%}{{ block.settings.image | image_url: width: 1500 }} 1500w,{%- endif -%}
                                {%- if block.settings.image.width >= 1780 -%}{{ block.settings.image | image_url: width: 1780 }} 1780w,{%- endif -%}
                                {%- if block.settings.image.width >= 2000 -%}{{ block.settings.image | image_url: width: 2000 }} 2000w,{%- endif -%}
                                {%- if block.settings.image.width >= 3000 -%}{{ block.settings.image | image_url: width: 3000 }} 3000w,{%- endif -%}
                                {%- if block.settings.image.width >= 3840 -%}{{ block.settings.image | image_url: width: 3840 }} 3840w,{%- endif -%}
                                {{ block.settings.image | image_url }} {{ block.settings.image.image.width }}1500w"
                            src="{{ block.settings.image | image_url: width: '1500px' }}"
                            loading="lazy"
                            alt="{{ block.settings.image.alt | escape }}"
                            width="{{ block.settings.image.width }}"
                            height="{{ block.settings.image.width | divided_by: block.settings.image.aspect_ratio }}"
                        >
                    </div>
                    <div class="banner__media {% if block.settings.image == blank and block.settings.image_2 == blank %} placeholder{% endif %}">
                        <img 
                            class="hidden-desktop"
                            srcset="{%- if block.settings.image_2.width >= 375 -%}{{ block.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 375 }} 375w,{%- endif -%}
                                {%- if block.settings.image_2.width >= 550 -%}{{ block.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 550 }} 550w,{%- endif -%}
                                {%- if block.settings.image_2.width >= 750 -%}{{ block.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 750 }} 750w,{%- endif -%}
                                {%- if block.settings.image_2.width >= 1100 -%}{{ block.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 1100 }} 1100w,{%- endif -%}
                                {%- if block.settings.image_2.width >= 1500 -%}{{ block.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 1500 }} 1500w,{%- endif -%}
                                {%- if block.settings.image_2.width >= 1780 -%}{{ block.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 1780 }} 1780w,{%- endif -%}
                                {%- if block.settings.image_2.width >= 2000 -%}{{ block.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 2000 }} 2000w,{%- endif -%}
                                {%- if block.settings.image_2.width >= 3000 -%}{{ block.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 3000 }} 3000w,{%- endif -%}
                                {%- if block.settings.image_2.width >= 3840 -%}{{ block.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 3840 }} 3840w,{%- endif -%}
                                {{ block.settings.image_2 | image_url }} {{ block.settings.image.image_2.width }}550w"
                            src="{{ block.settings.image_2 | image_url: '550px' }}"
                            loading="lazy"
                            alt="{{ block.settings.image_2.alt | escape }}"
                            width="{{ block.settings.image_2.width }}"
                            height="{{ block.settings.image_2.height }}"
                        >
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {%- endfor -%}  
    
    <nav class="aside__nav">
        <ul class="aside__triggers" role="list">
            {%- for link in section.settings.menu.links -%}
                <li class="aside__trigger-container">
                    {%- if link.links != blank -%}
                        <aside-menu>
                            <details id="Details-AsideMenu-{{ forloop.index }}">
                                <summary class="aside__trigger">
                                    <span>{{ link.title | escape }}</span>
                                </summary>
                                <ul id="AsideMenu-MenuList-{{ forloop.index }}" class="aside__links" role="list" tabindex="-1">
                                    {%- for childlink in link.links -%}
                                        <li class="aside__link-container">
                                            {%- if childlink.links == blank -%}
                                                <a href="{{ childlink.url }}" class="aside__link">
                                                    {{ childlink.title | escape }}
                                                </a>
                                                {%- else -%}
                                                <details id="Details-AsideSubMenu-{{ forloop.index }}">
                                                    <summary class="aside__sub-trigger">
                                                        <span>{{ childlink.title | escape }}</span>
                                                    </summary>
                                                    <ul id="AsideMenu-SubMenuList-{{ forloop.index }}" class="aside__sub-links">
                                                        {%- for grandchildlink in childlink.links -%}
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="{{ grandchildlink.url }}" class="aside__sub-link">
                                                                    {{ grandchildlink.title | escape }}
                                                                </a>
                                                            </li>
                                                        {%- endfor -%}
                                                    </ul>
                                                </details>
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        </li>
                                    {%- endfor -%}
                                </ul>
                            </details>
                        </aside-menu>
                        {%- else -%}
                            <a href="{{ link.url }}" class=""{% if link.current %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}>
                                <span {%- if link.current %} class=""{% endif %}>{{ link.title | escape }}</span>
                            </a>
                    {%- endif -%}
                </li>
            {%- endfor -%}
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic navigation never have accurate number of navigation links. It's better to call a collection in navigation. So you will get the featured image and if you want a different mobile image for that you can add image picker option. Below HTML code add in header.liquid of your DAWN theme.

```js
  //megamenu hover
  let items = document.querySelector(".header__inline-menu").querySelectorAll("details");
  items.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
                          item.setAttribute("open", true);
    item.querySelector("ul").addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
       item.removeAttribute("open");
    });
    item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
      item.removeAttribute("open");
    });
  });
});

//megamenu image show on hover
var $activeElement = $(".megamenu-text");
$(".custom-mega-img").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".megamenu-img").addClass( "active" );
   }, function(){
  $(".megamenu-img").removeClass( "active" );
    });
```

```css
details-disclosure>details {
    position: inherit;
}
.list-menu--disclosure {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    width: 90% !important;
  min-width: 90% !important;
  z-index: 2 !important;
      height: 30vh;
}

span.megamenu-img{
  text-align: center;
  width: 65%;
}
.desktop-feature-img{display: none;position: absolute;top: 0;}
span.megamenu-text{width: 35%;}
span.megamenu-img.active .desktop-feature-img {
    display: block;
  z-index: 2;
}

.list-menu__item--active .desktop-feature-img {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="{{ childlink.url }}" class="header__menu-item custom-mega-img list-menu__item link link--text focus-inset caption-large{% if childlink.current %} list-menu__item--active{% endif %}"{% if childlink.current %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}>
  <span class="megamenu-text">{{ childlink.title | escape }}</span>
  <span class="megamenu-img">
       {% if childlink.object.featured_image != blank %}
            <img src="{{ childlink.object.featured_image | img_url: 'medium' }}" class="desktop-feature-img"> 
        {% endif %}
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it guide me really, but i cannot make that appear what does mean that childlink.object.featured_image? i cant found nothing about that.

Comment: can you check at preview site please? i managed to get closer but it needs some edits on it. I wanna get something similar to eu.kith.com